# How can I tell the linker which one of multiple implementations of a method to use?

Tags: macos, linker, clang

I use a tool to generate a 111k-lines long C++ class implementation. The methods it generates work as they should, but they tend to trigger a slow path in the APIs that they use.

Is there any way, with Clang on Mac OS X, that I can manually implement some of the most-used methods in a different source file and tell the linker (or any other relevant program) to ignore the tool-generated method if another implementation for that method exists?

I am in complete control of the tool's output, though it would be pretty hard to automatically generate better code.

Comment: Which tool is it that you're using to generate the 111k-lines long C++ class implementation?

Comment: It's a tool that I made, which a LLVM IR module and transforms it into C++ code, where there is a 1:1 mapping between module functions and C++ methods. Each method generates the IR of the matching function, except with constant parameters, so the code can very easily be specialized and optimized and then analyzed. It has a very special purpose.

Comment: It's dirty, but if the tool is generating sufficiently modular code then `#include_next` of the relevant "more efficient" header does this without too much headache.

Comment: @CodaFi, I'm not sure I understand your solution. The idea is that I manually specify a more efficient implementation, not a more efficient declaration.

Comment: The idea is, given that the tool and you can generate 2 different headers (or more), that you break the implementation of functions into different headers and #include_next when you feel a particular implementation is more worth it in the "efficient" header rather than the "tool-generated" one.  Yeah it's not a link-time change, it's a CPP change, but I'd rather have modularity than futz around with the DYLD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is delivered in a library, then the linker searches through the .o files in successive libraries until all unresolved symbols have been satisfied.  So if your code generation can ensure the weak code is separated into different .cpp files, then you can deliver the custom written versions in an earlier .a on the link path, which will be used before the .a supplied by the code generation.

Alternatively, if you could add a false template into your code, then you could specify an explicit specialization for the code.  This would be used by the compiler/linker as it is a specific specialization.

Comment: The linker will complain that multiple definitions of the symbol exist with the .a method, unless there's a trick there.

Comment: It chooses the .o files in the library to satisfy each dependency.  So if a .o file contains multiple items, yes the linker will complain.  However, if each method is in a different .cpp file, then it will be in a separate .o, and the linker will add only the unsatisified symbols back in.  If you can code generate your weak methods into a single.o file, then that would be sufficient

Comment: I didn't realize that the linker would only take symbols that it needed from a .a and that duplicate symbols would quietly be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The tool-generated methods need to be marked as *weak externals*.  In GCC and clang  [this is achieved](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html) with `__attribute__((weak_import))`.   Then, if your hand-crafted equivalents are strong externals (as they are by default), they would take precedence over the generated ones.

Comment: I know you can use `weak_import` for externals, but I don't know that you can do it for methods that will be statically linked within the executable. I tried with [this](http://pastebin.com/p0Furpgy) and I get a duplicate symbols error for `X::y`.

Comment: Why does it make a difference if the method is statically linked?

Comment: my hypothesis is that weak imports rely on dyld filling the PLT/GOT entry with a null pointer, and statically-linked symbols, which are not imports, don't need that indirection and thus don't have the opportunity of being nulled out. Besides that, I don't think that `weak_import` means that the symbol is coalesced. These symbol classes are described on [Apple's Mach-O file documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/executing_files.html).